# How to display a tensor image in google colab?? Please find error in my code

Tags: image, pytorch, google-colaboratory, display, tensor

I am not able to display am image kept on drive. Please help in correcting the code.

Here is the code:

```
`import cv2
 import torch
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/GANcoursera/0148.png')
 print("Ori image shape", img.shape)
 img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # Convert BGR to RGB
 img_tensor = torch.FloatTensor(img.transpose((2, 0, 1)))  # Transpose dimensions
 print("Original image shape:", img_tensor.shape)
 def show_tensor_images(image_tensor):
 image_tensor = (image_tensor + 1) / 2
 image_tensor = torch.clamp(image_tensor, 0, 1)
 plt.axis('on')
 plt.imshow(image_tensor.permute(1, 2, 0))
 print("final image shape:", image_tensor.permute(1, 2, 0).shape)
 plt.pause(0.001)
 plt.show()
show_tensor_images(img_tensor)
```

`

[This is the original image kept on drive which is to be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjCno.jpg)

This is the **OUTPUT **:

Ori image shape (339, 510, 3)
Original image shape: torch.Size([3, 339, 510])
final image shape: torch.Size([339, 510, 3])

[This in the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeKsV.png)

I am not able to understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

he issue seems to be that you are not actually displaying the image in the output, but instead displaying the tensor shape. To display the image, you can use the plt.imshow() function after converting the tensor back to a numpy array using the .numpy() method.

```
import cv2
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/GANcoursera/0148.png')
print("Ori image shape", img.shape)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # Convert BGR to RGB
img_tensor = torch.FloatTensor(img.transpose((2, 0, 1)))  # Transpose dimensions
print("Original image shape:", img_tensor.shape)

def show_tensor_images(image_tensor):
image_tensor = (image_tensor + 1) / 2
image_tensor = torch.clamp(image_tensor, 0, 1)
npimg = image_tensor.permute(1, 2, 0).numpy()  # Convert tensor to numpy array
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(npimg)
plt.pause(0.001)
plt.show()

show_tensor_images(img_tensor)
```

Comment: It is not working. It's giving the same output image. I am not really getting where is the problem.